# Handling with php uploaded image via jquery.ajax and formdata

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need help on how to output the image and image data using php when uploaded using the code below or in other words how to handle upload with PHP

```
function uploadFile(blobFile, fileName) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("fileToUpload", blobFile);

    $.ajax({
       url: "upload.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(response) {
           // .. do something
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
           console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `success` function to query for the image that was just uploaded. Then you can append the image to the spot on the page where you want it to be displayed.

See [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: and how do i move image to the upload folder ??